# Remove dots from number

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a column with numbers formatted as general

```
| 2.500,00 |
| 70,2     |
| ...      |
```

I have a macro that tries to delete the dot in the column.

When I do it manually the result is

```
| 2500,00 |
| 70,2    | 
| ...     |
```

When I do it with the following line:

```
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

it removes the comma in the cells where there is no dot, the result looks like this:

```
| 2500,00 |
| 702     |
| ...     |
```

Comment: This is a culture issue. You are using the comma as a decimal separator but Excel appears to be set to use the dot as the decimal separator.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2013 or later, take a look at the `NUMBERVALUE` function.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the file from US and i am editing in France but I have tried to change the formatting and it doens't work and the question of why manually works is still there

Comment: So it seems the data is shown as text `=text()` is True at first. But then Excel is changing it to number, correct?

Comment: is shown as text before and after the macro is run

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening to your comma. I'm not getting the same result. Is there something else going on?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the format to Text before running the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the decimal separator used in Excel to comma instead of dot to match your data.

Copied from Microsoft: [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

> Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image, and then click Excel Options.
>
> On the Advanced tab, under Editing options, clear the Use system separators check box.
>
> Type new separators in the Decimal separator and Thousands separator boxes.
>
> TIP: When you want to use the system separators again, select the Use system separators check box.
>
> NOTE: For a permanent solution, you must change the regional settings in Control Panel.

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

Actually what I usually do is just use a formula to remove dots and convert comma to dot. Then use formatting to show the number however you want.

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),",","."))
```

Comment: would be great to show the solution in VBA to temporarily change this feature and then turn it back on (if need be) so OP can implement right into his code.

Comment: this made it, as @ScottHoltzman says I will need to implement it in the macro which I haven't figure out yet. However, now I have loads of spaces before the number itself and only in some

Comment: I want to keep the comma as decimal separator so why would I change it for a dot?

Comment: @D_Bester i added a replace for the spaces and it works, so forget about the spaces part, ill try to do the settings through with vba :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Application.DecimalSeparator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2):

Use the decimal separator defined by the application instead:

```
Selection.Replace What:=Application.DecimalSeparator, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Also using comma as decimal separator. When replacing dots manually, I had no problems at all, when I had VBA do it, commas were replaced and data got corrupted. What helped me was that I first used the trim function in excel, then I pasted it as values and only after that I replaced the dots with "nothing".

Here's the code:

```
    Sub dot_replace()

'first, trim cells
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
    Range("M1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M1:M3")
    Range("M1:M3").Select
'copy and paste as values
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'then proceed with replacing
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Hope this helpes someone

Answer (score 0):

my solution, using loop and replace function;
input: values in the column "D", number format "00.000,00-" for negative numbers (for positive without minus sign);
output: numbers in the format ("-00000,00) to be in the column "E";

```
'i is number of the row
Dim i As Integer
'1 is heading
i = 2
'lastRow in the number of the last row
Do While i <= lastRow
    'store value to be converted as string
    Dim str As String
    'convert from "00.000,00" to "00000,00"
    str = Replace(Range("D" & i).Value, ".", "")
    'myNum: number to be outputed
    'needs to be double, otherwise risk of errors or loss of decimals
    Dim myNum As Double
    myNum = 0

    'check for negative (format "00000,00-"
    If Right(str, 1) = "-" Then
        'remove minus sign
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
        'convert to double and make negative
        myNum = CDbl(str) * -1
    Else
        'not negative, simply convert do double
        myNum = CDbl(str)
    End If

    'store in the column with the output
    Range("E" & i).Value = myNum
    'continue on the next line
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1.Range("E:E").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False